# How to i add catalog/cart rule discount information to an email

Tags: orders, cart, email-templates, cart-rule, catalog-price-rules

when the user makes an order if they have items which trigger a discount from a catalog or cart rule under the item they get a small note indicating what rule the item has triggered and items that get a discount has how much they have been discounted by at the end, this is consistent in the cart, previous orders and printable version of previous orders

however i have noticed that emails sent out do not have this information, looking at both `app\design\frontend\enterprise\[THEME]\template\sales\order\invoice\items\renderer\default.phtml` which handles the display for previous orders display and `app\design\frontend\enterprise\[THEME]\template\email\order\items\order\default.phtml` which handles the display when making the email, they both use a `foreach` loop on what is returned by `$this->getItemOptions()` (the first one stores it in a variable and uses that while the second one just calls the function) but it seems that the second one doesn't have the catalog/cart rule information

we want to display the catalog/cart rule information in the email like what it does in in the cart and previous orders display so how do we add this infomation os that when the email is sent out the customer can see which items got a discount and by what (just like in the cart)

EDIT: we're using Enterpise 1.13.0.2

Comment: you could try contacting the enterprise support channels at magento.

Answer (score 1):

I can't look into enterprise templates, but I think adding this is quite easy. You have the discount and the price, so you can just add the information into either the method or into the template.